# Probability space for modified roulette

Tags: probability

> There are two roulette tables, at which you win with probability $p$ and $1-p$,$p\in (0,1)$ respectively. In game A you flip a coin. Dependent on the outcome you choose a table and play 2 roundsat it. In game B you flip a coin, play a round at the table dependent on the outcome, flip a coin again, and play another rounddependent on the outcome. Let $W_k$ be the event that you win the $k$-th round. Define a measurable space on which we can realize both games and show:
>
> i) In game A the events $W_1,W_2$ are not independent.
> ii) Game B is fair and the events $W_1,W_2$ are independent.
> iii) How do we have to rig the coin to make game A independent?

The biggest problem for me is actually defining the space. My idea was define $S=\{heads,tails\}\times\{win,loss\}$ and then take $S\times S$. This would model game B, but I don't think I can realize game A in it. I am fairly sure I'm able to prove the statements once I have this sorted out.

Comment: One way is to use what you have ($S \times S$) and for game A define the probability so that events H then T and T then H both have probability $0$. BTW, can you define events $G_1, G_2$?

Comment: It's just $G_1=\{\{heads,tails\}\times\{win\}\times S\}$ and $G_2=\{S\times\{heads,tails\}\times\{win\}\}$, right?

Comment: Is $G_1$ meant to be $W_1$? Or vice versa? You define $W_k$ but ask about $G_1,G_2$.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry $W_i=G_i$, I'll change it.

Comment: I tried defining the probability measure, but I'm having trouble with defining it properly for game A. Can you hel me with that?

Comment: Since the sample space has only $2^4=16$ outcomes, you could just list the probability value for each of them. i.e. write values for P(HWHW)=__, P(HWHL)=__,etc. For Game A, eight of them will be zero: the ones of form P(H_T_) and P(T_H_).

Answer (score 0):

Let $q$ be the probability that the coin in game A selects the "$1-p$" table.
That is, the probability of winning the first round is
$P(W_1) = (1-q)p + q(1-p),$ and so forth.
For independence, we want $P(W_1)P(W_2) = P(W_1 \cap W_2).$

I find that
$$P(W_1)P(W_2) - P(W_1 \cap W_2) = (q^2 - q)(1 - 4p + 4p^2).$$
Set the left-hand side to zero, and then we just need to solve for $q$ (if we can) 
under the condition $p \in (0,1).$

I think there is a flaw in the problem statement, because if $p=\frac12$ then
it seems to me that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are already independent for the original
game A (where $q=\frac12$), and certainly $\frac12 \in (0,1).$
If so, part i) is not strictly true.
I think we were meant to assume that $p \in (0,1)\setminus\{\frac12\}.$

(Edited to write $W_i$ instead of $G_i$ since the problem statement was updated
to use $W_i$ consistently.)

Comment: I don't think this is right. I get $P(G_1)=q(1-p)+(1-q)p,P(G_2)=qp(1-p)+(1-q)(1-p)p$,$P(G_1 \cap G_2)=q(1-p)^2+(1-q)p^2,0=P(G_1)*P(G_2)-P(G_1\cap G_2)=...=p^2+\dfrac{1}{3}-p\quad$ which has no real solution (q=0.5).

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, you are correct, $p=0.5$ is a solution.